# Crash + Rejection from App Store: scene-create watchdog (React Native)

Tags: ios, react-native, exception, app-store, watchdog

I'm posting here because I have no clue what to do, and can't find an answer elsewhere. I'm using React Native.

I was rejected from the app store with this error that occurred on two devices they used, meaning my 'foreground' didn't load in time:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, <RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:scene-create watchdog transgression: application<--->:666 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 19.63 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 30.050 (user 30.050, system 0.000), 26% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 4.161, 4% CPU" | ) reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>
```

However, I have never run into this issue during testing, (Using react native) and have been in beta with 20+ users who have never had this issue. I literally cannot reproduce the error, and I have no clue what to do next. My app is always loading within 3 seconds or so, and i've never experienced this issue.

How do I go about this? What could possibly be happening? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tested in a pure IPv6 network?  Have you tested your app with no network connection?

Comment: Ah, that's a great question. I have not.

Comment: @AndrewYoung did you find out a solution? I'm having the same issue here.

Comment: @ErickMaeda Possibly, I deployed the app in "Build" mode by accident, so I fixed that and deployed in release and haven't had this issue since. Not sure why that would be a problem, but make sure to check that.

Comment: Hmm ok, it's very strange, I also was able to solve it by just recreating the archive and send it again. Apple now approved without any change :s

Comment: Yeah it may be the testers bad internet or something